# Cannot push commited local code on main branch to remote repo

Tags: git, github

I have been trying to push my react code to the remote repo but it does not work and the message I recieve is

```
remote: warning: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/14.pack is 57.55 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/6.pack is 57.53 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/12.pack is 58.54 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 36316f83c9d3fbf7a089cc7214646ff11823b74ac7e958d3a028245d6cd3a0c8
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/17.pack is 102.91 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/1.pack is 153.82 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/4.pack is 153.81 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/9.pack is 110.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/RichieMuga/Asset-Management-System.git/
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/RichieMuga/Asset-Management-System.git/'
```

I have excluded my node modules folder and my gitignore is the following(but still, no luck :(  )

```
# /node_modules
# node_modules/
.env
# eslint cache
.eslintcache
./node_modules
node_modules/
*.nc
*DS_store
```

I have installed gitlfs as another alternative and the file is as follows

```
.js filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.pack filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# /node_modules filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs
*.nc filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.csv filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pack filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Kindly if anyone can assist me, please help.

Comment: Just my two cents. If this is a fresh repository - with only a few commits, consider making a new one, but this time, make sure to exclude properly the node modules. But if not, I'd use Sourcetree or similar GUI to remove modules and stop tracking it in my next commits.

Comment: do a `git rm -r --cached .`

Comment: here you go https://techstacker.com/remove-node_modules-after-adding-gitignore/

Comment: The error i'm getting ```fatal: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any files``` @AbdullahSaleem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+files+history